# From deterministic little o to stochastic little o notation

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, proof-verification, weak-convergence

I have a question on Lemma 2.12 in van der Vaart which can be found [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=UEuQEM5RjWgC&pg=PA13&lpg=PA13&dq=Lemma%202.12%20van%20der%20Vaart%20let%20R%20be%20a%20function%20defined&source=bl&ots=mnSCTD8WJC&sig=L_6S-Rq8_t3jPgBPCTnNyuk_zQE&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwkeOc7avKAhVB1BoKHf-aBDkQ6AEIHzAA#v=onepage&q=Lemma%202.12%20van%20der%20Vaart%20let%20R%20be%20a%20function%20defined&f=false).

Consider statement (i): if $R(h)\in o(||h||^p)$ as $h\rightarrow 0$ $\Rightarrow $ $R(X_n)\in o_p(||X_n||^p)$.

Among the sufficient conditions for (i) to hold we have $X_n\rightarrow_p0$ where $\rightarrow_p$ denotes convergence in probability.

The proof of (i) is articulated in the following steps:

(1) Define a function $g$...

(2) Show that $X_n\rightarrow_p0$ $\Rightarrow$ $g(X_n)\rightarrow_pg(X)$ by continuous mapping theorem, i.e. $g(X_n)\in o_p(1)$

(3) Rewrite $R(X_n)=g(X)||X||^p$

(4) Conclude that $R(X_n)\in o_p(||X||^p)$

> Question: by continuous mapping theorem we also have that
>   $X_n\rightarrow_p0$ $\Rightarrow$ $||X_n||^p\rightarrow_p0$, i.e.
>   $||X_n||^p \in o_p(1)$. Hence, this combined with step (2) implies that $R(X_n)=g(X)||X||^p\in o_p(1)$. What is
>   wrong in this last statement?